# How to group by / Order by with logical sequence

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a problem in SQL (QGIS). I have a shape with plots. I would like to obtain a certain organisation. 
Here a schema of what I have and what I want :

[image]

Comment: There is no native function to do this, programming is necessary, sql or python is a good option. Are you used to programming?

Comment: I'm using DBManager in QGIS where I can write SQL function ;-)

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using? I.e. what is the data backend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For PostgreSQL:**

```
SELECT section,
       ARRAY_AGG("number" ORDER BY "number") AS "numbers",
       CONCAT_WS(' ', 'from', MIN("number"), 'to', MAX("number")) AS "sequence"
FROM   (
  SELECT *,
         SUM(incr) OVER(ORDER BY section, "Condition", "number") AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN LAG("Condition") OVER(ORDER BY section, "number") = "Condition"
             THEN NULL
             ELSE 1
           END AS incr
    FROM   <your_table>
  ) q
  WHERE NOT "Condition" = 'No'
) q
GROUP BY
       section, grp
ORDER BY
       section
;


  section | numbers |   sequence    
 ---------+---------+-------------
  A       | {1,2}   | from 1 to 2
  A       | {4,5,6} | from 4 to 6
  B       | {1,2}   | from 1 to 2
 (3 rows)
```

Here,

- the `CASE` statement will assign and incrementor (`incr = 1`) to rows whose `"Condition"` is different from the previous row
- the `SUM` creates a running sum to serve as group value (`grp`)

Comment: Hi ! I've install PostgreSQL and did your expression and it work well thank you ! But it doesn't create column, What do I have to put in your expression to complete it with a creation of the column "sequence" ?

Comment: @LéoChevrier I need something to debug...what's the error message, if any? This may be caused by a plethora of small issues, wrong syntax etc. . Is your `number` column actually any numeric type? Or e.g. `TEXT`?

Comment: There is no bug with your expression. The result appear in "**Data output**". What I needed was to create another table but I find a way : I copy past the result in CSV file then I work with in QGIS. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @LéoChevrier oh I see...well that's simple, just run `CREATE TABE <table_name> AS <insert_above_query_here>;`

Comment: @LéoChevrier btw. if this helped you solve the issue, please accept the answer as correct (click that greyed out little tick next to the question)

Answer (score 3):

I give you part of the answer with some thoughts, the path to adopt according to me.

First, you need to **create a new field** that you can use to group your values.

Without this field, it's complicated to express your need:

> Aggregate me the numbers by section, but when you meet the condition "No" you aggregate in another group.

You must arrive at the following result:

[image]

Secondly, you can **execute the following sql query** using the method `array_agg` to aggregate your values in an array.

```
SELECT section, array_agg(number) as number -- use the array_agg method
FROM test  -- name of your layer
WHERE "group" != '0'  -- exclusion of the no condition
GROUP BY section, "group" -- group by with the field previously created
ORDER BY section, number
```

The result is the following :

[image]

Comment: Is it not bad practice to use a sql-keyword as a column name :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, it was so that the example would be more understanding ;p

Comment: Ok thank you !!!

What would be the function for create the new field 'group' ?

Comment: There is no native function to do this. Geozelot gave you an answer using PostgreSQL which offers more functions than in the DB Manager. To create this field you can use Python via the console in QGIS. You will need to consult the QGIS API documentation.

Answer (score 3):

**Not exactly** what you asked for, **but** if you can live with the section being only one row, sqlite has a group_concat function making it very simple:

```
select section, group_concat(number) numbers
from mytest
where condition <> 'No'
group by section
order by number
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Don't know why but with the same expression my numbers aren't well order ? https://imgur.com/a/UtawxyW

Comment: From the doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html: "The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary."

Comment: You can order the source table first before using group concat by using a subquery https://stackoverflow.com/a/1897372/11418874